# Why did Loki lie to Thor that Odin was dead?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, loki, thor-2011

In the first Thor film (2011), Loki visits Thor in his exile in Earth and tells him that their father died, that "the burden of the throne" has fallen to him, and that their mother has forbidden his return.

**Why did he tell him Odin was dead?**

It seems to me that this lie was completely unnecessary. Thor had no way of returning to Asgard anyway, and, if anything, Odin being alive would have given a better excuse as to why Thor can't come back - it makes sense for Loki not to want to undo Odin's last wish while he was still alive. And later on, this lie was how Thor discovered Loki was manipulating the whole situation and why he was willing to fight back.

What was the point of this lie? Was it only to make Thor suffer?

Comment: I felt like it was designed to dishearten him. By removing his entire support structure, it makes him less likely that he'll return, at least until Loki has consolidated his grip onto the Throne of Asgard

Comment: If whoever downvoted this question could explain why, I'd be very happy to know...

Comment: Single downvotes are rarely worthy of note. Some people just don't like certain questions, others fat-finger the button when they mean to upvote.

Comment: ...and some people accidentally downvote when they forget they can't check the vote total on mobile. :-P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The goal was to prevent Thor from making any attempt to return to Asgard, at least while Loki conducts his semi-coup and conspires to have Odin attacked so that he can rescue him (and hence become King of Asgard instead of Thor).

By kicking away Thor's support structure (banning his friends from 'rescuing' him, making Bifrost travel illegal, telling him that his father is dead, that peace with Jotunheim is conditional on his continued banishment and that his mother is in agreement) Thor is basically left with no good reason to return to Asgard and, crucially, nobody to appeal to.

Had he told him that his father was in Odinsleep, Thor might have realised that the whole series of events (the interruption of the throning ceremony and the way that he convinced Thor to undertake rash actions in revenge) was part of Loki's wider plan to take over the throne.

On top of that, it makes Thor feel bad, which we know is something [that Loki quite enjoys](https://youtu.be/bbq2mYimFrY?t=12).

> The implications of Loki's words dawn on Thor -- he's responsible for his father's fate. Loki draws close to him, looks in his eyes, consolingly.
>
> <sub><sup>[Thor: Screenplay](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html)</sup></sub>

and

> **FANDRAL:** *We're here to take you home.*
> [Jane reacts to the news of Thor leaving.]
>
> **THOR:** You know I can't. **My father is dead because of me. I must remain in exile.**
>
> [The other Asgardians exchange puzzled looks.]
>
> **SIF:** *Thor... your father still lives.*
> [Thor reacts to the revelation.]

Comment: All in all I agree with you, but I have two notes: 1) Loki didn't conspire to have Odin killed, but almost killed, so that he could rescue him and be a hero. 2) In my opinion Loki doesn't *enjoy* watching Thor suffer; in fact, to me it seems he is at times even sad to see him suffer. He's just dying to show he is not inferior to him, that he's also worthy, etc.

Comment: @Wade - Loki was largely unconcerned about his father's fate. He could easily have been killed during the invasion, but you're right. When it comes to the pinch he saves Odin.

Comment: I saw the clip you added, but I still disagree that he enjoys watching Thor suffering - to me what Thor mentioned in the clip sounds just like a prank. Still, I agree with everything else, so +1

Answer (score -3):

Loki never felt he belong despite the Odin family embracing his blue self. The loathing, shame and guilt he felt is what drove him to humiliate Thor at every turn, as Thor was naturally better at everything. When Loki visited him at Shields camp, his look when he turned away was a Loki original of mischief

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any support for this?  "Loathing, shame and guilt" seems perhaps to overstate the case a bit; just for starters, you don't need self-loathing to be jealous.